# (Unix) Changing A Row To A Column In A Text File

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I currently have a text file that has the following data in row format:

```
TIME (HR) 0 6 12 18 24 36 48 60 72 84 96 108 120
```

I would like to "flip" this row into a column so that it reads:

```
TIME (HR)
0
6
12
18
24
etc...
```

Is there a way to do this with sed/awk?

Comment: It might be possible. First, though, it would be good to know when a new line should be included. What pattern did you think about? Also, what did you try so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grep could do:

```
grep -Po '.*\)|\d+' file
```

this line works too:

```
grep -Po '.*?(?= \d)|\d+' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
TIME (HR) 0 6 12 18 24 36 48 60 72 84 96 108 120

kent$  grep -Po '.*\)|\d+' f
TIME (HR)
0
6
12
18
24
36
48
60
72
84
96
108
120
```

Comment: Won't this insert a newline after `TIME` also?

Comment: @anubhava changed into a grep line, to make TIME and () together.

Comment: i think it would be better if your code is `grep -Po '.*\)|\S+' file`

Answer (score 3):

Through awk,

```
awk '{print $1,$2;for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file
```

Through perl,

```
perl -pe 's/(^\S+\s+\S+)(*SKIP)(*F)| /\n/g' file
```

Comment: Ya just a small change from `<` to `<=` and +1 for the good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another perl one:

```
perl -pe 's/\s+(?=\d+)/\n/g'
```

Test:

```
$ echo 'TIME (HR) 0 6 12 18 24 36 48 60 72 84 96 108 120' | perl -pe 's/ (?=\d+)/\n/g'
TIME (HR)
0
6
12
18
24
36
48
60
72
84
96
108
120
```

Another GREAT solutions (from the comments from @AvinashRaj)

```
perl -pe 's/\s+(?!\()/\n/g'
perl -pe 's/ (?=\b)/\n/g'
```

Comment: it won't work if the input contains  non-space characters other than the digits.

Comment: op's  has mentioned clearly that he has a single space between non-space chars.. :-)

Comment: another better one for you `perl -pe 's/ (?=\b)/\n/g' file` :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' '{ORS=(NR<2?" ":"\n")}1' file
TIME (HR)
0
6
12
18
24
```

Comment: it adds an extra space at the last.

Comment: Yes it does. That's part of the `etc...` expected output the OP requested :-). Just changing RS to `RS='[[:space:]]+'` solves that if the OP cares and is using GNU awk for multi-char RS.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/ \([0-9]\)/\
\1/g' YourFile
```

posix version (so `--posix` for GNU sed)
chanage any space followed by a digit by a return. Digit is keep in memory and set back bacause there is no back reference in sed regex